# UIPageViewController/TextKit Multipage flow in SWIFT

Tags: swift, ios8, uipageviewcontroller, textkit

Has anyone had any luck creating a multiple page view of document (one, NSTextStorage, one NSLayoutManager, and multiple NSTextContainers) in Swift. I'm having a lot of trouble finding example code not in objective C.

Basically, I'm trying to recreate the "Advanced Text Layouts and Effects with Text Kit" demo from WWDC 2013, but the whole thing is in Objective C and there is no sample code to be found. The post below seems to be having luck; but I'm having no luck translating...

[UIPageViewController/TextKit Reflowing Text on paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710845/uipageviewcontroller-textkit-reflowing-text-on-paging)

Comment: Swift is new and quickly evolving. For now, being a competent iOS / OS X developer means being able to at least read ObjC and ObjC-based documentation fluently, even if you only write Swift.

Comment: Thanks rickster... To be clear, my problem is not reading ObjC, but translating it into Swift.

Answer (score 0):

http://rshankar.com/quotes-app-simple-page-based-application-in-swift/

This uses the Page Based Application project template for a out-of-the-box working example, then customize for the model you want to use.

It use this same technique in my app by changing the root controller to what ever viewController I want it to be, coping the three files into my app, and all the magic is done for me.